# AJAX Request with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a script that fetches a word definition from a database. It's working fine, but as soon as I include Bootstrap's CDN link in the header it no longer works. There is no error, but the script simply won't fetch the result.

I have tried different CDN links, but I'm stuck. Below is my script. I have not included the PHP script that response with JSON to the jQuery AJAX script because it works fine too.

How can I fix my script? Right now, even simply inserting the CDN link in the header make the script stop working.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#word-submit').on('click', function(){
    var word = $('#word').val();
    if ($.trim(word) != ''){
      $.post('ajax/name.php', {word: word}, function(data){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(obj);
      });
    };          
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <form autocomplete="off" class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" id="word" >
        <input type="button" id="word-submit" value="Tam" class="sr-only" >
      </form>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/global.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Load your boostrap script AFTER you load your jquery file. Bootstrap has hard dependency on jQuery.

Comment: Sorry. I do not understand by what you mean "bootstrap script". I have only bootstrap css file. How do I load it after my jquery file? I tried putting the css link after jquery.js, but nothing happened.

Comment: insert `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` between your `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="js/global.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>`

Comment: Actually I think you can make this work just by wrapping your body scripts in a function and calling the function after they are loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't load an entire page like that using Ajax. You should only be loading the information contained in the body. If you have additional css / javascript files then you should append them to the page once you've loaded the content from Ajax.